# Similar circuit not working because of wire

Tags: breadboard

[image]

I've setup a series circuit with an LED and a 1kohm resistor. If I plug the led positive end (longer end) directly to the power positive rail, it lights up.

[image]

But if I connect the led positive end to the positive rail with a wire, it does not light up. This looks exactly like the same circuit to me. Nothing has changed other than now there is a wire. What's going on?

Comment: "Nothing has changed other than now there is a wire." False, the LED moved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "How is the breadboard wired internally?"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The holes in each row are connected together.

Your second circuit has both pins of the LED shorted together.

---

Just so the photos from grom neer referred to in the comments don't get lost.

Here's the sketch:

[image]

The lower sketch shows what happens when you plug an LED into a row of sockets on a breadboard.

This is the schemstic diagram that shows the same thing:

[image]

The LED is shown short circuited as will happen if both pins of the LED are plugged into one row on a breadboard.

Comment: By shortening, do you mean this? ibb.co/YNMLfrK image section #2 bottom side. As in, #1 is what I thought was happening. But in fact, it's #2?

Comment: Not ["shortening."](https://www.crisco.com/products/vegetable-shortening)  "Shorted" an in "short circuited."

Comment: Yes, your drawing is what I meant.

Comment: Okay and one more thing, is this diagram I made an accurate representation of what's going on? https://ibb.co/55Tbphr. It appears the circuit is still complete and current flows through the resistor. But not in the led/diode component. Because it has been shorted.

Comment: Yes, the schematic diagram is correct.

Answer (score 14):

You're shorting the LED in the second photo. The rows of the breadboard are electrically connected to each of the holes in the same row. Like this:

[image]

To add, the two columns on the left and right are connected to each hole in the same column. Like this:

[image]

Edit: Pictures are not original, i took them off Google images. Here is the site they originated from:
https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard-and-build-a-led-circuit--mac-54746

Comment: By shortening, do you mean this? https://ibb.co/YNMLfrK image section #2 bottom side. As in, #1 is what I thought was happening. But in fact, it's #2?

Comment: Are these your own pictures?

Comment: Please add links or citations for the images you copied into your answer. We want to make sure that the original creator receives credit for their work.

Comment: Done! Sorry, wasn't trying to take credit for what wasn't mine. Just didn't think about it..